# How do I get AWS to return a status code showing that the JWT used for authorization has expired?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, authorization

I'm using the serverless framework with AWS to develop a webapp based on API Gateway / Lambda. I'm using JWT for authentication and authorization, writing a custom authorizer which is attached to the API Gateway config by serverless.

My strategy at login is to issue an "access" token which has 60 mins validity, and also a "refresh" token which has 8 days validity. If the user tries to access the system more than 60 mins after the access token was issued, the client app will call a refresh_token API authenticated by the refresh token (and that's the only API that this refresh token will allow), to obtain a new pair of tokens. And so the user will only need to re-enter username/password details if they're dormant for more than 8 days, otherwise they keep refreshing tokens, giving the system a chance every 60 mins to boot them out if they've been blacklisted.

This strategy is working fine, except that I can only find how to accept or deny access to an API based on parsing the JWT - not pass back a specific status code to the client ("Token expired - you need to refresh" kind of thing).

So in my `module.exports.user = (event, context, callback) => {}` function I `callback('user','Deny',methodArn)` but that doesn't give any clues to the client about why the user's request has been denied.

However, it's notable that there is no standard HTTP status code for this situation - just the generic 401. So is there a better way to solve this, and am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Just realised I can look at the JWT at the client end to see if it's expired, and if so refresh it. No need to waste a trip to the server and try to find out why it's been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on the original question. Realised that I can check for expiry on the client and head straight for refresh rather than trying and failing to use it for authentication with the server.